# Typescript error while passing link as parameter to a function

Tags: typescript

I am using Nextjs 14 here.

```
import Link from "next/link";

const Links = [
  {
    title: "Homepage",
    path: "/",
  },

  {
    title: "About",
    path: "/about",
  },
];

return (
  <div>
    {Links.map(
      (link) =>
        (
          <Navlink item={link} key={link.title} />
        )`passing navigation link as parameter to the below component NavLink`,
    )}
  </div>
);

const Navlink = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={item.path}></Link>
  )`Error path is not part of the element`
};
```

Error I am getting

> Binding element 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type

But not able to find the type of the item. What is the correct type?

I have tried to define the type of the {item} like HTMLElement React elements but every time getting error "path" is not part of the element.`

Answer (score 0):

that's a nice question what's happening here is that your `Navlink` component is isolated and never informed about where or how you'll use it, then TS can't infer the data-type.

I can see two possible solutions:

1. (Recommended) For your specific scenario you may not need `Navlink` component because it does not extend the functionality of your component at all.

```
  <div>
    {Links.map(
      (link) => <Link href={item.path}></Link>
    )}
  </div>
```

2. (If you didn't upload the full code) and you're extending a ton of functionality you should create the type/interface for your component props.

```
interface LinkItem {
  title: string;
  path: string;
}
```

And using like this in your component:

```
const Navlink = ({ item }: { item: LinkItem }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={item.path}>
      {item.title}
    </Link>
  );
};
```

I hope it's helpful for you!

Comment: Thank you @Sebastian Bárcenas for your suggestion. Now I am getting the below error while passing the link as parameter.

 `  return (
      <div className={styles.links}>
          {Links.map((link => (
          <Navlink item={link.path} key={link.title} />
      )))}    
      </div> `  

Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'LinkItem'

Comment: To fix that instead of sending `<Navlink item={link.path} key={link.title} />` you can send `<Navlink item={link} key={link.title} />` it should fix your problem. This is because you're using the custom component created.

Don't forget to check my response as correct if it worked for you!